# Word Cloud - Getting Top N Word Frequency

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with multiple columns. One of the columns is "action taken." Each row of the column is a sentence. My task is to identify which top words in the actions taken column have been used the most number of words.

I am using a word cloud to visualize this. The word cloud gives me an additional feature to use stop words which are essential for my task. The word cloud also gives me the flexibility to filter based on slicers, which are also very necessary for my purpose.

The problem is that I only want to visualize words that have the top N (let's say, 50) frequency in the word cloud. I could not find any option to do this.

Can anyone help me out to filter out the top 50 most occurring words in the column? The only restriction is that I should be able to apply slicers and stop words ( or any equivalent of stop words).

I have tried copying the column as a separate query in PowerQuery and making it a list of words, but that does not help as I am unable to use the slicers based on other columns on the new word cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You could summarize your table so you'll have a count of each "action taken", and base the Word Cloud on that

```
Actions Taken = SUMMARIZE(TableName,TableName[action taken],"count",COUNT(TableName[action taken])
```

- Category is [action taken]
- Values is [count]
- In the Visual Level Filters select the Top N filter for [action taken]
- "Show Items:" is Top and 50
- By Value is [count]